# outlook.office.com vs outlook.office365.com

Tags: http, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We have configured our server to serve an Outlook Add-in using

```
X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://outlook.office.com"
```

Our app was rejected by Office Store because it's being tested on `outlook.office365.com`. We don't see a way to allow multiple domains (i.e. `outlook.office.com` and `outlook.office365.com`)

Could you please help us here?

PS: When will we completely migrate to one of these ?

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Frame-Options` header can only support a single domain for `ALLOW-FROM`.

As for Outlook Web Add-ins specifically, it isn't safe to assume `outlook.office.com` as the host domain. The origin could be any number of known domains (`outlook.office.com`, `outlook.office365.com`, `outlook.live.com`, etc.) or even a custom domain (OWA with an on-prem Exchange Server for example).

It is also worth noting that `X-Frame-Options` isn't [fully supported across browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility). Generally, unless you're looking to blanked `DENY` rendering in a frame `X-Frame-Options` isn't very robust. And given that Office Web Add-ins by definition run within an `IFRAME` within a browser, it is likely going to cause far more problems than it solves.

Comment: this is pretty much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334839/x-frame-options-for-outlook-web-add-ins

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT What is the suggested way to get it working in iframe and take care of clickjacking too?

Comment: Given that preventing clickjacking means preventing another site/app from framing your app, there isn't a good option here. After all, the entire point of your add-in is that you _need_ it to be framed by another app.